# Why twice bind on onClick is required in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `LandingPageComponent` which has a child component `DisplayStudent`

I have a function `deleteStudent` in `LandingPageComponent`. I'm passing this function as a prop to `DisplayStudent` but I can't understand why I need to bind `function deleteStudent` in `LandingPageComponent` and `DisplayStudent` as well

I need to get `id` when delete button is clicked see this on jsFiddle

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytm0o35b/1/)

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import DisplayStudent from './DisplayEmployeeComponent'

var data = [{
    name: 'student-1',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'student-2',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'student-3',
    id: 3
  }
];

export default class LandingPage extends Component {
  deleteStudent(e) {
    console.log('hi', this, e)
  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      DisplayStudent studentData = {
        data
      }
      deleteStudent = {
        this.deleteStudent.bind(this)
      } // BINDING FIRST TIME
      /> < /
      div >
    )
  }
}

export default function(props) {
  return (
    props.studentData.map((ele) => {
      return ( <
        div key = {
          ele.id
        }
        style = {
          {
            display: 'flex',
            padding: '9px 5px 7px 4px'
          }
        } >
        <
        div > {
          ele.name
        } < /div>

        <
        button onClick = {
          props.deleteStudent.bind(this, ele.id)
        } // binding second time
        >
        Delete <
        /button> < /
        div >
      )
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: if you want to bind a method you should bind it in constructor not in render method,If you don't want to use bind just use Arrow functions instead

Answer (score 3):

Without `.bind(this)`, `this` inside `deleteStudent` points to the global object (`window`), not to your component.

Learn more about [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) and [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Isn't the first `.bind()` unnecessary though, he just needs to pass it from my knowledge of how it works, and then bind it inside the component that uses it

Answer (score 1):

You should `bind` it once.If you do it twice the second one doesn't apply.
It's best practice to implement it on `constructor` just after `super`
For more read [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid first bind even second bind in ES6. Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/bayucandra/xch1L072/9/

**Explanation:**

**1st bind**

```
  deleteStudent = (e) => {
    console.log('hi', this, e)
  };
```

This is a new way of how we do `bind(this)` for ES6 in Babel. Just syntactic sugar to the old way. The old way is by doing `bind(this)` in the constructor.

**2nd bind**:

```
      <button
        onClick={props.deleteStudent.bind(this, ele.id)}
      > Delete
      </button>
```

You need those `bind()` because you need to pass `ele.id` as `e` argument from : `props.deleteStudent(e)`

if you don't want to pass it that way, you can use fat arrow of ES6 as follow:

```
      <button
        onClick={() => props.deleteStudent(ele.id)}
      > Delete alternative
      </button>
```

That way above you will bind function which calls `props.deleteStudent(ele.id)` inside of it.

Comment: can't it be achieved without using fat arrow ??

Comment: It can't be achieved without bind or fat arrow. Because you need to pass an argument there. doing `onClick={ props.deleteStudent }` will mean `e` argument value === `undefined`. Actually fat arrow just syntactic sugar of `function(){ return props.deleteStudent(ele.id) }`. Technically you just bind a function to `onClick`.

Comment: Even there is a way without `bind()` and fat arrow, it will end up with much complicated way :)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't required. `props.deleteStudent.bind(this, ele.id)` is misleading because `this` isn't usable inside functional component (it's either a global or `undefined`) but it doesn't affect `deleteStudent` because it's already bound to proper context.

If the intention is to bind a callback to proper context, it preferably should be bound once in class constructor:

```
export default class LandingPage extends Component {
   deleteStudent = this.deleteStudent.bind(this); // syntactic sugar for a constructor

   deleteStudent(e){
       console.log('hi', this, e )
   }

   render(){
       return(
           <div>
               <DisplayStudent studentData = {data}
                            deleteStudent = {this.deleteStudent}
            />
           </div>
       )
  } 
}
```

And if `deleteStudent` should be provided with specific argument instead of the one that will be passed on click event (event object), a cleaner way is wrapper function:

```
<button onClick={() => props.deleteStudent(ele.id)}>Delete</button
```

Comment: By this way I will not get `this` inside `deleteStudent` I mean `this.setState({})` will not work inside `deleteStudent` since `this` is `undefined`

Comment: Do you have a problem that can be reproduced? `this` can't be undefined inside `deleteStudent` because `deleteStudent` is already bound to correct `this` inside `LandingPage`.

Comment: yes it can be reproduce just try it on jsfiddle that I have mentioned in my post

Comment: What do you mean? console.log outputs correct `this` and there will be no problems with `this.setState`. It will do so as well with changes suggested in the answer.

Comment: ohh got it You have bind in it the constructor .

Answer (score 0):

Binding 2 times is not needed at all. Bind is used to pass this reference inside function. So, the first bind inside `LandingPage` 'DisplayStudent' is enough. Also it is advisible to bind this in constructor, as everytime `LandingPage` re-renders it is passing a new refrence of function to `DisplayStudent`. The second bind in onClick is just used to pass parameter to function.

P.S. You can use arrow function to avoid such confusions